# If/Elif/Else Statement in Python - Else Statement prints even though the if constraints are being met

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, output

I am in my first month of programming and I have encountered an issue in an app I'm developing. I'm sure it's fairly simple for someone experienced but I don't know how to fix it without a syntax error. Here's my code (see below for output error)

```
def what_to_find():
    find = (input(": "))
    if find == int(1):
        find_slope()
    elif find == int(2):
        find_elevation1()
    elif find == int(3):
        find_elevation2()
    else:
        print("Choose a number corresponding to what you want to find")


what_to_find()
```

So the input function works, but regardless of what number I put in (either 1, 2, or 3), the 'print' under the else command always prints. Here is what the output is for example:

What are you trying to find?
1 = Slope, 2 = Higher Elevation, 3 = Lower Elevation
: 1
Choose a number corresponding to what you want to find
Insert higher elevation:

So I have more code after this which creates the prompt for the higher elevation, but I just want to know how to make sure it doesn't print the else statement once it runs. Also I am using Visual Studio Code for my IDE.

From a very inexperienced coder, thanks in advance for your help!

UPDATE: After revising and using input from others, this is what I have:

```
def what_to_find():
    find = int(input(": "))
    if find == 1:
        find_slope()
    elif find == 2:
        find_elevation1()
    elif find == 3:
        find_elevation2()
    else:
        print("Choose a number corresponding to what you want to find")


what_to_find()
```

Which all made sense, put this becomes the output (after I plug in one of the corresponding numbers of the if statement):

```
What are you trying to find?
1 = Slope, 2 = Higher Elevation, 3 = Lower Elevation
: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcalc.py", line 24, in <module>
    what_to_find()
  File "gcalc.py", line 15, in what_to_find
    find_slope()
NameError: name 'find_slope' is not defined
```

Not sure how this occurred or why the change to the beginning 'find' made this output. Please help me out! Thanks

Comment: The condition isn't true. Think about what type `input` returns, and what type `1` is.

Comment: You're casting the wrong value. Try `int(find) == 1`

Comment: `type(find)` is `str`. You are comparing `str` with `int`. `str` and `int` are not equal.

Comment: Thank you guys! I will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate the overhead of doing `int(find)` on each of the if statements, just implement the required condition on the initial user input so like this:

```
 find = int(input(": "))
```

and then each if statement can be  just checking for the value like this:

```
 if find == 1:
   #run this scope
```

etc etc...

Comment: Totally makes sense, but please see my update to my question. The output is now not working after the input is made and I am not sure why.

Comment: so in the updated code, you are invoking 3 other functions that maybe of the same class or from another file that are not defined within this scope..you have to see where `find_scope()` is defined, how it's defined and how to call it (which you mostly have done). or what do those functions represent as that's the gist of the scope..

Comment: Ok I will keep working to see if I can get it to run and will let you know. Thanks for the help, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this

Comment: maybe you can add the other portions on here as well, and see if the community can see where the error is :)

Comment: I got it! I was calling the what_to_find() before the defined function find_slope(). Once I moved the function call what_to_find() below it, it was able to find find_slope() and run! Thanks for your help!